# AJAX textfield automplete, when selected, how to change value of a combobox?

Tags: ajax

I don't really know AJAX, I'm only using a bit of its feature in my project. I used its autocomplete feature in a textfield, which connects to a mysql database. Now I want it so that when a person is selected, his/her corresponding rank (which should also be acquired the database) will automatically be the value of the combobox ([something like this](http://i56.tinypic.com/10if6om.png))...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial applies a value after select to a text field and the combobox.

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/

Be sure to check the demo:

http://www.jensbits.com/demos/autocomplete/

```
$(function() {

        $('#abbrev').val("");

        $("#state").autocomplete({
            source: "states.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
                $('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);
            }
        });

        $("#state_abbrev").autocomplete({
            source: "states_abbrev.php",
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
```